# how to query Kinesis Streams using Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

here is my scenario,
we are passing all click stream data to Kinesis and then sending it to Firehose, which saves the data to S3 after 1 minute.

In order to query the data, i have to wait for a minute atleast. 
i want to Query the stream to get latest user action for a particular user, i was thinking of using Lambda to Query Kinesis Stream.

please suggest/advice if there is a better way to query Kinesis streams for real time data ?

Comment: Have you looked into Kinesis analytics at all? That plugs in lambdas automatically I believe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we write an AWS Lambda function to query Kinesis Streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403211/can-we-write-an-aws-lambda-function-to-query-kinesis-streams)